# Is there a word for "not a ratio"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is there a word for "not a ratio," e.g. the stock increased by $100 on a *something* basis which is 50% on a percentage basis.

I used to think the word is *nominal* but I don't see that definition anywhere.

Comment: **Irrational** is used to describe numbers that can not be described as a ratio, but I don't think that is what you are looking for here.

Comment: An *absolute* basis.  (Percentage change is a *relative* measure.)

Comment: "Absolute" is the correct word, but why do you need "on a ____ basis" at all? The stock increased by $100, a 50% gain. What else needs to be said?

Comment: @remarkl Sometimes it sounds smoother to me. Eg The national debt seems reasonable as a percentage of GDP, but remains alarming when considered on an absolute basis.

Comment: @eliyahu I agree with your debt example because there are no numbers in it.  My issue was redundancy; absent numbers, there is nothing for the absolute/ratio to be redundant with.

Comment: @remarkl Fair, but that was intentional. In the question I was redundant in the question to make clear what I was asking, and not redundant in the comment to show why I am looking for a word like that at all.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you thought the word was *nominal* because of the influence of *nominal value*, a word [expressing the face value of notes, coins, and bonds](https://www.economicshelp.org/blog/glossary/nominal-value/). A $100 bond has a nominal value of $100. This is opposed to *real value* or *market value*, which is how much the bond might be worth at a given time. Sometimes this is used to refer to the raw value of a financial offering or holding, as [this report from Moody's shows](https://www.moodys.com/research/Moodys-Assigns-Aa3-to-Benicia-Unified-School-District-CAs-GO--PR_903583095?WT.mc_id=AM%7ERmluYW56ZW4ubmV0X1JTQl9SYXRpbmdzX05ld3NfTm9fVHJhbnNsYXRpb25z%7E20160912_PR_903583095):

> The rating incorporates the district's financial profile, which we anticipate will decline somewhat on a **percentage basis**, but will remain relatively stable on a **nominal basis**.

If you want an alternative, I'd suggest **numerical basis**, which would stand in for any raw comparison of numbers. This has some usage in the larger world of words, as [this report from KQED shows](https://www.kqed.org/news/142193/california-jobless-rate-falls-again-now-7-4-percent):

> Educational and health services posted the largest gains on a **numerical basis**, adding 103,400 jobs (up 4.5 percent). Information posted the largest gains on a **percentage basis**, up 5.1 percent (adding 22,800 jobs).